PowerShell: Write-Host not working as expected

While doing research for the commands I needed to get the right output I needed for an answer, I spent several hours trying to figure this out and couldn't determine why this isn't generating output the way it seems it should (occurs in both PowerShell 5 and 7).
The first returned line is out of format, with all subsequent lines of returned output being correctly formatted:

Current output:  ForEach | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-PSDrive | Write-Host
PS $ # Match drive serial numbers to their drive letter mountpoints:
       $drive = (Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[c-z]$'

       ""; Foreach ($letter in $drive) {
         Write-Host $letter': ' -nonewline
         Get-Partition -DriveLetter $letter | Get-Disk
       }


C:
Number Friendly Name                       Serial Number         HealthStatus    OperationalStatus    Total Size     Partition
                                                                                                                    Style
------ -------------                       -------------         ------------    -----------------    ----------     ----------
3      Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 1TB       S*************V       Healthy         Online                931.51 GB  GPT
D: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
H: 1      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************R       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
M: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
P: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
V: 3      Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 1TB       S*************V       Healthy         Online                931.51 GB  GPT

When directly copying terminal output, the issue becomes more perplexing:
C:
Number Friendly Name                       Serial Number         HealthStatus    OperationalStatus    Total Size     Partition
                                                                                                                    Style
------ -------------                       -------------         ------------    -----------------    ----------     ----------3      Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 1TB        S*************V                  Healthy              Online                  931.51 GB GPT
D: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
H: 1      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************R       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
M: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
P: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
V: 3      Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 1TB       S*************V       Healthy         Online                931.51 GB  GPT



Expected output:
Number Friendly Name                       Serial Number         HealthStatus    OperationalStatus       Total Size  Partition
                                                                                                                    Style
------ -------------                       -------------         ------------    -----------------       ----------  ----------
C: 3      Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 1TB       S*************V       Healthy         Online                931.51 GB  GPT
D: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
H: 1      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************R       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
M: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
P: 0      Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB             S*************H       Healthy         Online                  3.64 TB  GPT
V: 3      Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 1TB       S*************V       Healthy         Online                931.51 GB  GPT




This question belongs on Stack Overflow I have already voted to migrate it.

@Ramhound It's a question related to Powershell. I don't understand why it should belong to Stackoverflow when there are hundreds/thousands Powershell's questions  here at Superuser.

@ReddyLutonadio - You have a programming question about why the script output isn’t what you expect, is there a reason, you don’t want this question migrated to Stack Overflow? -nonewline might have something to do with not getting the expected output

@Ramhound Because I see these questions here daily/weekly. I see nothing unusual about this one. It can be answered here or there (Stackoverflow).

@ReddyLutonadio - If you truly believe that I encourage you to answer the question, your answer if the question is migrated will follow the question, migration to the correct community is helpful and positive for everyone

@Ramhound It is not about whether I can answer the question or not. If I ever answered the question whether here or Stackoverflow, it doesn't matter for me. And yes, the question must be answered in the correct community. Anyway, it's now up to the rest community and moderators to decide.

@Ramhound It's not to do with -nonewline, I tried executing with and without, as well as the commands individually. I'm wondering if it's a bug, but since I don't do a lot of PowerShell scripting and cobbled this together from looking up what I wanted to do, I wanted to ask before filing a bug report (it seems like a bug to me since it only affects the first returned line and none others)

Does it happen with PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 7+?

@Ramhound Both 5 and 7

@JW0914 - Given that information it means it’s not a bug within PowerShell

The output might not be what you expect but is displayed correctly. The code first outputs the drive letter followed by the results of Get-Disk.
Remember, column titles (Number, FriendlyName, etc) are displayed before the results of Get-Disk. During the first iteration, C: is written followed by the column titles, then its results. During the following iterations, the column titles are not displayed but only the results. That's why C: is outside while the other drive letters are "inside" aligned with the outputs.

Is it possible to retard the first drive letter iteration until after the columns are written, or would it be better to look for a different command combination to have it format the way I'm looking for?

@JW0914 I don't know if you can delay the first iteration. But you can try something like: `Foreach ($letter in $drive) {
$disk =  get-partition -DriveLetter $letter | get-disk
[PSCustomObject]@{
Drive = $letter
Number = $disk.Number
FriendlyName = $disk.FriendlyName
OperationalStatus = $disk.OperationalStatus
HealthStatus = $disk.HealthStatus
}
}` Not sure if that is what you want

Thanks! That throws an error, but gives me a place to start =]
